# Difference between wildfly 9.0.1 vs 8.2.1

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am seeing 2 versions (9.0.1 vs 8.2.1) of wildfly which were released on the same day. What is the difference between two versions and why there are 2 versions exist in parallel? I couldn't find it over the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildfly ships on a very fast development cycle. Each major release 8.x, 9.x, 10.x contains major changes from the previous version. All current major work is being done on the 10.x beta versions.

The minor versions are for bugfixes related to that particular release. Since there are now people in production with both 8.x and 9.x, any critical bugs or security patches go into one of these releases. It is very possible a security issue could exist and be fixed in both 8.x.1 and 9.x.1.

JBoss EAP, which is based on WildFly, deliberately has a slower release schedule. For each major version they release they offer paid support for 4 years, so they change major versions much slower.

There is a good slide of the lifecycle of WildFly/JBoss on page 9 of this slide-deck from the RedHat Summit in June:
http://videos.cdn.redhat.com/summit2015/presentations/12186_red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform-7-roadmap-new-features.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official announcement for the pair of releases: -

http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/23/WildFly-901-and-821/